# Escaping CDATA cause isXML as false for parsed XML

Tags: xml, coldfusion, xml-parsing, cdata

I am having a code snippet below, which is for checking whether the xml is valid or not using [isXML function of ColdFusion](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f67.html).

I have used

```
]]]]><![CDATA[>
```

instead of

```
]]>
```

for escaping CDATA.

I have found something strange happening here. i.e. isXML returns true for non-parsed XML and it returns false for parsed XML. Can I know why?

```
<cfsavecontent variable="test">
<TEST><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <type>XML</type>
    <mapping><![CDATA[<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <html>
                <body>
                <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
                <table border="1">
                  <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Artist</th>
                  </tr>
                  <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
                    <tr>
                      <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
                      <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
                    </tr>
                  </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
              </body>
            </html>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>]]]]><![CDATA[>
    </mapping>
</Configuration>]]></TEST>
```

```
<cfdump var="#isXML(test)#">
<cfdump var="#xmlParse(test)#">
<cfdump var="#isXML(xmlParse(test))#"><cfabort>
```

You can find [gist here](http://www.trycf.com/scratch-pad/gist/fc63996dd4e6cf7cde9e65423275d1b6)

Comment: `IsXML` determines whether a *string* contains valid/parsable XML. Given that `xmlParse` succeeded, you already know it is valid XML. So why would you even want to use `IsXML` on that object? :-) Maybe you are thinking of `IsXMLDoc`, which: *[Returns] True, if the function argument is an XML document object; False, otherwise*.

Comment: @Leigh You are correct. But It would work without CDATA (inside mapping). You can check this out here http://www.trycf.com/scratch-pad/gist/5a03e115ed8fee819cf95ead0703089f

Comment: (Edit) @user3107071 - Yes, but it is also using the function in a way that was not intended according to the docs.  To test for xml objects, use `IsXMLDoc` instead. As for the reason, it is likely because the function expects a string, so CF must convert the XML object first (and assuming the base string is valid XML) the resulting string is somehow different than the original. My guess is something like `ToString(xmlObj)` is used internally. If you dump the result, the string is different and fails the `IsXML` test. http://trycf.com/gist/2028fda4ee48a9c409d3984db6db2ed3/acf2016?theme=monokai

Comment: *...assuming the base string is valid XML* Might want to run both strings through an xml validator as well.